# Gloom Magic, Tiefling, and Street Magician, do they work together?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

> #### Gloom Magic (SP)
>
> A rogue with this talent gains the ability to cast darkness two times per day as a spell-like ability. The darkness created by this ability **does not impair the rogue’s vision**.

> #### Magical Racial Traits
>
> Spell-like ability: Tieflings can use darkness once per day as a spell-like ability. The caster level for this ability equals the tiefling’s class level.

Emphasis mine. Now my question is, Gloom Magic allows the rogue's vision to not be impaired, but is that only for the 2 uses of Darkness that it grants, or for all uses of Darkness, granted from this talent, the racial ability, or even [Street Magician](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/drop-dead-studios-rogue-archetypes/street-magician/)'s spells?

The reason I ask is I see 2 possible interpretations of spell-like abilities: they are pooled together and are all 1 ability, thus benefiting from Gloom Magic, or they are separate SLA's that just happen to be the same spell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tiefling can only see in the [Darkness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/darkness) created by [Gloom Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/gloom-magic-sp/):

> The darkness **created by this ability** does not impair the rogue’s vision.

Any other source of darkness will still require your character to have the [darkvision](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Darkvision) or [see in darkness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-See-in-Darkness-Su-) special abilities.